# Count All Occurrences Between Stop 1 and Stop 2 Over and Over again (Count Until?)

Tags: excel-formula

I need to count all occurrences of "overall delays" that fall on each day, i.e.: How many delays occurred on 3/30 for car ABC and XYZ.

I think the best way would be to count all that occur between stops 1 and 2 (ie: First_Last) but can't figure out the best way to do that (something like countuntil).

I can NOT do a query (Google Sheets) since I need to upload this as a CSV file into a querying software.

Anywhere in L2 through L9 I need to see a count of overall delays for car ABC example.

Hard to explain! My actual sheets is over a million lines long with 600+ routes. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MDH1-Na8Zruy1xvCO3spR-c5jrrHnbpU58ndu3EpIqI/edit#gid=0) is my example sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want a pivot table. Select the data set. Click data --> pivot table report, and pick the relevant fields for your columns/rows/values.

Added it to your sheet. Here's what it looks like:
[image]